# How to get Row_Number with partition by in Linq to entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-entities

I want to get row number per something group.

i found some article but it is not work in EF linq.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVZcv.png)

```
var aa = entity.PackOrderMedicineHistory.GroupBy(x => x.MedicineID)
.Select(g => new { Group = g, count = g.Count()})
.SelectMany(e => e.Group.Select(v => v)
    .Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, e.count), (i, j) => new {i.MedicineID, rn = j})).Dump();
```

this is article on web. But Linq to entity is showing below error
'NotSupportedException'

Could you give to me any idea so that i can get row number per some group ?

And i have another question.
Our some table has 25000000 record. i need to make some group and use aggregate function.
But query is very slow.. do i have get good query?

Comment: You need to use `AsEnumerable` to pull the SQL data over, then use the two argument lambda version of `Select` instead of `Zip`+`Enumerable.Range` to add the counts e.g. `e.Group.Select((v,rn) => new { v.MedicineID, rn })`.

Comment: could you let me know full sentence?

Answer (score 0):

You can process the group by on the server, then add the row number on the client side:

```
var aa = entity.PackOrderMedicineHistory.GroupBy(x => x.MedicineID)
               .Select(g => new { Group = g, count = g.Count()})
               .SelectMany(e => e.Group.Select((v, rn) => new { v.MedicineID, rn })).Dump();
```